# Raphael.js drag with scale causes weird jumping behavior

Tags: javascript, svg, resize, raphael, scale

I'm trying to resize/scale an image using Raphael.js's built in drag method, but I'm getting some weird behavior.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/charleshimmer/5pdyy/1/

Use the right or bottom right corner to resize the image.  You will see some weird behavior with it jumping and skipping using the scale method.  Anybody have any idea why?

I can get it to resize smoothing by updating the image's width and height, but then the aspect ratio is off. Using `image.scale`, the aspect ratio is maintained, but then it jumps all over the place.

Comment: So I've got it working.  I just need to calculate the ratio of the image using height / width and not off of the change in pixels.  I still need to adjust for how the image should resize depending on which side of the image the user is resizing the image from, but I've updated the jsfiddle link to reflect the working code in case anybody needs it.

Comment: You should answer your own question rather than leave a comment if you have managed to solve your problem. That way it will be more useful for others

Comment: Your question is currently at the top of the unanswered list for "svg" and "raphael" tags. Please answer your own question and accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Photo Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="editor"></div>
    <img id="image" 
         src="http://www.pyrblu.com/assets/launchpad_resources/demo.jpg"
         style="display:none"
    >
 </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
svg 
  {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background:#fff;
  border-radius: 45px;
  }
```

JavaScript

```
var Editor = {},
ctFactor = 7;

// create Raphael canvas
Editor.paper = Raphael('editor', 582, 514.8);

// wait for image to load
$("#image").load(function(){

    Editor.image = Editor.paper.image("http://www.pyrblu.com/assets/launchpad_resources/demo.jpg", 25, 25, 282, 465.2);

    Editor.image.drag(Editor.dragging, Editor.dragStart, Editor.dragEnd);
    Editor.image.ready = true;
    Editor.image.mousemove(function (e) {
        // only do this if the user isn't currently moving / resizing image
        if( ! this.ready){
            return;
        }
        var side = Editor.sideDection(e, this);
        // if the user's mouse is along the edge we want resize
        if(side){
            Editor.image.state = 'resizable';
        }
        // else it's towards the middle and we want to move
        else{
            Editor.image.state = 'movable';
        }
        var cursor = (side) ? side + '-resize' : 'move';
        this.attr('cursor', cursor);
    });

});

Editor.sideDection = function(event, ct){
    // check north side
    var directions = {
        n: Math.abs(event.offsetY - ct.attr('y')) <= ctFactor,
        s: Math.abs(event.offsetY - (ct.attr('height') + ct.attr('y'))) <= ctFactor,
        e: Math.abs(event.offsetX - (ct.attr('width') + ct.attr('x'))) <= ctFactor,
        w: Math.abs(event.offsetX - ct.attr('x')) <= ctFactor
    },
    side = '';

    // loop through all 4 sides and concate the ones that are true
    for(var key in directions) {
        if(directions.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            if(directions[key]){
                side = side + key;
            }    
        }
    }

    return side;
};

Editor.dragStart = function () {
    console.log('at start');
    // grab original x, y coords        
    this.ox = this.attr("x");
    this.oy = this.attr("y");

    // toggle user is doing something
    // so other actions are blocked
    this.ready = false;

    this.animate({opacity: .65}, 500, ">");
};

Editor.dragging = function (dx, dy, x, y, e) {
    console.log('at dragging');
    if(this.state === 'movable'){
        // this does the actual moving of the object
        this.attr({x: this.ox + dx, y: this.oy + dy});    
    }
    // we are resizing then
    else{

        var diff = (x - this.ox) - this.attr('width'),
            xratio = 1 + diff / this.attr('width'),
            yratio = 1 + diff / this.attr('height');

        console.log('diff: ', diff, 'xratio: ', xratio, 'yratio: ', yratio);           
        //resize image, update both height and width to keep aspect ratio
        // this.attr({
        //     'width': this.attr('width') * xratio,
        //     'height': this.attr('height') * yratio
        // });
        this.scale(xratio, xratio, 0, 0);

        //console.log('h: ', this.attr('height'), 'w: ', this.attr('width'), 'r', this.attr('width') / this.attr('height'));
    }
};

Editor.dragEnd = function () {
    this.ready = true;
    this.animate({opacity: 1}, 500, ">");
};
```